# How to determine the Website Administrator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, security

In an ASP.NET Project (C#) and SQL Server 2008, how should an Administrator be determined?

Should I have an **attribute** in my **Users** table to determine the Admin? Even though I have only 1 Admin?

```
id           username            type
--------------------------------------
1            Ali1                admin
2            James3              user
3            Carlos31            user
4            Kuku                user
```

OR

Should the Admin be determined by a special **ID** when checking the **Session** ?

Let's say the Admin is the user with the **id=1**

```
if(Session["id"].toString().Equals("1"))
{
    //Admin
}
else
{
    //Normal User
}
```

Which approach is better and more secure? is there a better one?

Comment: Why aren't you using the asp.net membership schema?

Comment: @adripanico This is my first ASP.NET project so I'm not familiar with ASP.NET stuff, I prefer "classical coding".

Comment: I suggest you to research about it because it can agilize a lot of the process. I followed this tuto (http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not check for a specific id, but rather for a user type.  You don't know if the data will ever change or if you'll ever have to add additional admins.  It's generally a bad idea to hard code values like this in your application.  Instead, create a UserType class and check for a UserType.Admin or UserType.User role and handle the code in your BLL and/or DAL.

So to answer your question, you're first implementation would work well.

Good luck.

Comment: @AiBassam: And this also gives you the ability to easily promote some normal user to admin and vice versa... (+1 for this answer)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a schema like:

http://dbpatterns.com/documents/50851b3189cbad4b9fd5b45a/

So you have a user table and a level table.

In the level table have something like:

```
id           level
-------------------
1            admin
2            user
```

Then in the user table give each user a level number, that way you can just add levels easily and have a definition to lookup against.

**Or if you wanted to go overkill:**

Have a 3rd table storing the user ID and the level ID so users could have more than one role

In the user_level_link table have something like:

```
user_id    level
-------------------
1            1
2            1
2            2
```

Definitely don't do it against a single ID as it can cause issues when you intend to scale the site further.

Comment: Incorrect, you can add as many rows with as many roles are you'd like.

Comment: Yes, but one user can have just one role.

Comment: You don't assign multiple roles to a user, each role should be defined to be specific. Also you could simply store an array in against the user such as (1,2,6) if you really wanted to have multiple roles for one user.

Comment: That's the worst solution I've ever heard. That totally breaks the relational model.

Comment: Well you could add a 3rd link table, but I think that's going beyond the askers requirements.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a 3rd table, despite it not really being required for this user.

Comment: Nice solution, but It's too big for only a Admin/User role, this is good for different roles and different privileges, Admin, Half-Admin, Moderator..etc.. but thanks for the Idea.